# Using toString method but the combo box still doesn't show values

Tags: java, swing, tostring

I have a JFrame form in my Java application, it has several comboboxes that are populated as they should be, except one that shows something that does not have meaning (like transfer.TransferObject@859ae5....), I did toString method in the class which the combo box is referring to (I did the same for other combo boxes and they work normally), but this one combo is still showing this transfer.TransferObject@859ae5... 
For example, mz combo box should show names of patients, so in the Patients class I do this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

but it works everytime, except now for this combo. What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: That "meaningless"(It's not) string is the value of the default toString() method. Make sure you are overriding and calling it correctly.

Comment: I am calling it correctly. WHat else could be a problem here?

Comment: @user2370759 Show the entire class.

Comment: I can't post the entire class because I don't have enough messages yet. But the class where I am using toString() only contains constructor and getters and setters.

Comment: Ideally it should. I am sure there is some silly mistake. To track it, put the debugger in toString() method and see if it getting called or not.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `toString` method should work but is not a good practice. I suggest you implement a `ListCellRenderer` instead, something like this:

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if(value != null){
            if(value instanceof Patient){
                Patient p = (Patient) value;
                setText(p.getName());
            } else {
                setText(value.toString());
            }
            if(isSelected){
                setBackground(...);//set background color when item is selected
                setForeground(...);//set foreground color when item is selected
            } else {
                setBackground(...);//set background color when item is not selected
                setForeground(...);//set foreground color when item is not selected
            }
                return this;
        } else {
            // do something
            return this;
        }
    }

}//end of MyClass declaration
```

Then you have to set an instance of this class to your JComboBox **before** adding items to it:

```
yourJComboBox.setRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
/* Now you can add items to your combo box */
```